# Slide down navigation with list items moving

Tags: jquery, html, css, navigation

I have a navigation that slides down in a way that background color slides down and the list items fade in, but are not moving from the top downwards and that is what i would like to achieve.

Must be simple by adding a top value with addClass/removeClass, but can't seem it to work within the javascript.

Note: .nav-toggle is the hamburger icon which is the trigger that works fine.

Hope someone can help me.

[--> Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Pallum/kk2xtr8ze/4/)

Javascript:

```
// Navigation //

$(function() {
$('.nav-toggle').click(function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('nav ul.right-nav').slideFadeToggle(300);
    $('.nav-toggle').toggleClass('is-active');
})
});

$(window).scroll(function() {
if ($(this).scrollTop() > 50) {
    $('nav ul.right-nav').hide();
    $('.nav-toggle').removeClass('is-active');
}
});

$.fn.slideFadeToggle  = function(speed, easing, callback) {
return this.animate({opacity: 'toggle', height: 'toggle'}, speed,  easing, callback);
};
```

Html:

```
<header>
<nav>
    <div class="mobile-nav">
        <div class="nav-toggle"><i class="nav-icon"></i></div>
    </div>
    <ul class="left-nav">   
        <li class="home"><a href="#">Pixelation</a></li>    
    </ul>
    <ul class="right-nav">  
        <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've modified your jQuery, check [**this**](https://jsfiddle.net/kkxtr8ze/6/) out.

```js
// Navigation //

$(function() {
    $('.nav-toggle').click(function() {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('.right-nav li').slideToggle(300);
        $('.nav-toggle').toggleClass('is-active');
    })
});

$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 50) {
        $('nav ul.right-nav').hide();
        $('.nav-toggle').removeClass('is-active');
    }
});

$.fn.slideFadeToggle  = function(speed, easing, callback) {
    return this.animate({opacity: 'toggle', height: 'toggle'}, speed, easing, callback);
};
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* width and height value includes content, padding and border not the margin */
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0); /* remove highlight on touch devices */
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%; /* sticky footer  */
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

body {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.3;
  letter-spacing: 0.02em;
  color: #000;
  background-color: transparent;
}

h1, h2, p, nav {
    text-rendering: optimizelegibility !important;
}

b, strong {
  font-weight: normal;
}

a:link, a:visited {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

h1, h2, nav a {
  font-weight: normal;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-column-span: all; /* break out the column flow */ 
          column-span: all;
}

h1, nav a {
  font-size: 21px;
  text-align: center;
}

/************************************************
Navigation
************************************************/

header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
  background-color: transparant;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.mobile-nav {
  display: none; /* hide mobile nav */
}

nav {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 0; /* remove default spacing */
}

nav ul.left-nav {
  float: left;
}

nav ul.right-nav {
  float: right;
}

nav li {
  display: inline-block;
}

nav a {
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  margin: 0 10px;
  line-height: 60px;
}

nav ul.right-nav a:link, 
nav ul.right-nav a:visited {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav ul.right-nav a:hover,
nav ul.right-nav a:focus, 
nav ul.right-nav li.selected {
  color: #000;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}

/************************************************
Navicon
************************************************/

.nav-toggle {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 0;
  left: 10px;
  z-index: 3;
}

.nav-icon {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 7px;
  margin-bottom: 7px;
}

.nav-icon, 
.nav-icon:before, 
.nav-icon:after {
  display: block;
  width: 24px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: black;
  -webkit-transition-property: background-color, -webkit-transform;
  -moz-transition-property: background-color, -moz-transform;
  -o-transition-property: background-color, -o-transform;
  transition-property: background-color, transform;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.2s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.2s;
  -o-transition-duration: 0.2s;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
}

.nav-icon:before, 
.nav-icon:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
}

.nav-icon:before {
  top: -7px;
}

.nav-icon:after {
  top: 7px;
}

.nav-toggle.is-active .nav-icon {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.nav-toggle.is-active .nav-icon:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(7px) rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: translateY(7px) rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: translateY(7px) rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: translateY(7px) rotate(45deg);
  transform: translateY(7px) rotate(45deg);
}

.nav-toggle.is-active .nav-icon:after {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-7px) rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-7px) rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-7px) rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: translateY(-7px) rotate(-45deg);
  transform: translateY(-7px) rotate(-45deg);
}

/************************************************
Responsive
************************************************/

@media screen and (max-width:1012px) {
   .size-m {
    max-width: 700px; /* bigger text width */
   }
}

@media screen and (max-width:667px) {
    .compact-group .compact-item {
      width: -webkit-calc(50% - 2px * 2);
      width: calc(50% - 2px * 2);
      /* when max-width is less than this value it will 
      always display two resizing thumbnails next to each other */
    }
}

@media all and (min-width: 668px) {
    nav ul.right-nav {
      display: block !important;
    }
}

@media all and (max-width: 667px) {
    header {
      position: fixed;
      background-color: red;
    }

    .home {
      background-color: white;
      padding-left: 50px;
      padding-right: 50px;
    }

    .nav-up {
      top:-44px; /* hide navigation on scroll */
    }

    .mobile-nav {
      display: block; /* show mobile navigation */
    }

    nav {
      padding-left: 0;
      padding-right: 0;
    }

    nav ul.left-nav {
      float: none;
    }

    .right-nav {
      float: none;
      /* display: none; */
    }

    nav li {
      width: 100%;
    }

    nav a {
      display: block;
      margin: 0;
      line-height: 44px;
    }

    nav ul.right-nav a:hover,
    nav ul.right-nav li.selected {
      text-decoration: underline;
      border-bottom: none; /* remove border when mobile */
    }

    .grid-wrapper {
      margin-top: 60px;
    }
}

@media all and (max-width: 600px) {
    body { 
      font-size: 18px;
    }

    h1, h2, nav a {
      font-size: 21px;
    }

    h1 {
      margin: 0 0 20px 0;
    }

    p {
      margin: 0 0 20px 0;
    }
}

@media all and (max-width: 480px) {
    .grid-item a:hover img {
      opacity: 1.0;
    }   

    .copy {
      padding: 20px 10px;
    }

    .copy-img {
      padding: 20px 0;
    }

    .caption {
      display: none; /* remove caption on mobile devices */
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
 <nav>
  <div class="mobile-nav">
   <div class="nav-toggle"><i class="nav-icon"></i></div>
  </div>
  <ul class="left-nav"> 
   <li class="home"><a href="#">Pixelation</a></li> 
  </ul>
  <ul class="right-nav"> 
   <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
 </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Thanks, but is it possible that they stay inline and not floating downwards on top of each other?

Comment: Sorry but is doesn't seem to work, but it is a lot of extra code. I was more thinking to adjust the nav ul.right-nav when in mobile mode position: absolute, width: 100% and add and remove a class that will change the top value -88px to 0px.

Comment: It is clearly working. The menus side down from the top as you wanted

Comment: Sorry now i see it. It works after 480px media query. Thank you it is a bit more code than i would like to see, but thank you.

Comment: There are many other ways to do it, you just need to look for it. Glad to be of help. If you appreciate my answer then kindly mark it as answer

Answer (score 0):

use `function(event)` instead of `function()`

in your script

```
$('.nav-toggle').click(function(event) {
        //  code
}
```

Demo - https://jsfiddle.net/kkxtr8ze/5/

Comment: Sorry but i can't seem the difference what i already had working?